# Swift- Concatenating Tuples

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

How would one join two tuples

```
(1,2,3) (4,5,6)
```

to form

```
(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. Tuples aren't really like arrays—they're not even treated as sequences, really—so you can't join two together.

Comment: You can't concatenate *any* two tuples, but of course, if you know their lengths, you can combine them to make a new tuple.